# SLD for OS Mastermap

Tags: mapserver, sld, os-mastermap

We are just looking into moving from MapServer to GeoServer for some of out WMS needs, one of which is to serve OS MasterMap to our users.
Before I have a go at creating the SLD styles for MasterMap does anyone have any they have created that they are willing to share?

Comment: OS forums has guidlines for ITN Roadlinks in OS MasterMap - http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/itnforum/thread.jspa?threadID=841 but "I'm afraid we don't have any other SLD files for other layers of MasterMap. It is expected that users will work though the style guides to create their own and tailor colours and lines to suit individual requirements."

Comment: Thanks Mapperz, I posted on that forum and got a response from OS. I was more asking if anyone had a good example of there work they were willing to share before i sat and did the work. Lazy i suppose, but do we not all want similar styling for the basic MasterMap and then Change to suit specific projects?

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking for some SLD files I have attached a link to a zip file with SLD and QML for OS MasterMap.  These were created using QGIS and so may need some tweaking to work with GeoServer.

http://words.mixedbredie.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Styles.zip

Answer (score 2):

I can not help you directly, but I have two suggestions for indirect procedures:

1) If someone has the appropriate styling available for you as ESRI ArcMAP lyr-files an easy way forward is to generate SLD-files using [GeoCat Bridge](http://geocat.net/bridge)

2) Geoserver as WMS-forwarding. This means you can cache up any WMS-service and forward it for internal (or external) use. You should of course make sure you are not breaking any copyright regulations for the primary WMS-layer.

Other than this I can strongly recommend using Geoserver.

Answer (score 1):

Youve probably sorted your requirements by now but there's now a set of SLD's available under opn licence: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/support/products/styled-layer-descriptors/index.html

Julian

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Julian. 
5 years later, the link to the SLD files has changed to
https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/OSMM-Topography-Layer-stylesheets

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GetStyles SLD operation on a MapServer WMS to get an SLD representation of the style used by MapServer